# Dummy placeholder

Tags: scala, syntax

How do I make a return type which is a subtype of all other types. I want the following

```
def foo(): (String => String) = TODO
def bar(): String = TODO
def baz(): Int = TODO
```

What type should `TODO` be?

Comment: By the way what you're trying to do is already available in [std lib](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L252): `def foo(): Int = ???`

Comment: I would take this as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Too bad you didn't just write a short correct answer.  Behold the "wrong" answer.  Consider that people argued over whether to call it TODO or other names.  It's OK to have your own TODO, but in fact everyone wound up loving ??? which bespeaks universal adoption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>"A subtype of all other types" in Scala is `Nothing`. You may do something like this:</s>

<s>`def foo(): (String => String) = TODO`</s>

<s>`def bar(): String = TODO`</s>

<s>`def baz(): Int = TODO`</s>

<s>`def TODO: Nothing = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented")`</s>

**EDIT**:

OK, as OP accepted my answer for a strange reason and people keep upvoting it (for an even more strange reason) I feel responsible to change my answer. All credits go to [om-nom-nom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298389/om-nom-nom):

The thing you are looking for is already implemented in [Scala Standard Library](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L252) and works like this:

```
def foo(): Int = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

`Nothing` is a subtype of every type, which has no habitants. It's the type of a `throw`, so simply implement tge method body by throwing

```
def todo(): Nothing = throw new NotYetException
```